# using substring-before - searching for a specific string and then extracting another

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am a beginner to xslt. I am trying to search a long string for value in my case "EMRUPI", and I need to extract the ID prior and populate another field.  I'm using the "substring-before" function

i can not seem to extract the value, it returns NULL

This is the data:

```
PID|1|12345^^^ABCMRN^MRN^|678988^^^DEFMRN^MRN^~111111^^^GHIMRN^MRN^~7777777^^^EMRUPI^CMRN^||
```

I basically want to find in the PID3 segment (PID3 is the data after the 3rd pipe "|") the text 'EMRUPI' and grab the id prior to that '7777777'.
I want to save it in a variable eg $EMRUPI and put it into PID4 segment which is what i am trying to do here:

here is the script i wrote:

```
<PID>
    <F3>
                <xsl:variable name="EMRUPI" select="substring-before(name(),'EMRUPI')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(name(),'EMRUPI')" />
                <L1.1.1><xsl:value-of select="$EMRUPI"/></L1.1.1>

    </F3>

    <F4><L1.1.1><xsl:value-of select="$EMRUPI"/></L1.1.1></F4>
</PID>
```

Comment: This is not trivial to do in XSLT 1.0. Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? You could really use some extension functions here, if your processor supports them.

Comment: If you don't know, find out - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: Hi Michael im using definately XLST 1.0.  Could you let me know what you suggest with extension functions, i am not sure what you mean here.  Any advice is really helpful.  thanks!

Comment: Hi Michael, i am reading now about extention functions but in the meantime is there any reason why my code is not working? it would be quicker to get this working or if there is another inbuilt function i could use?  thanks

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me, I am afraid (especially your use of the `name()` function). It would be quicker (for me anyway) if you answered my question.

Comment: Another thing that may help here is an explanation of the delimiters used by your input string.